# How to exclude some path/page from client certification in Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate

I am trying to set up an Apache server with client certification enabled. So that the customers could access the content with a valid client certificate.

Let's say, I have the server running as

```
https://myserver/myservice/
```

Also I need to provide an interface to my customers to get their client certificates by providing some authentication information to

```
https://myserver/myservice/register
```

Once the uploading information verified, it returns a client certificate.

If I understand correctly, this path should be excluded from the client certification mechanism, simply because it is used to generate certs. So the question is, how can I specify the httpd config to achieve this?

My current configuration goes like:

```
ProxyPass /myservice/register http://localhost:4444/register

<Virtualhost *:443>
    ServerName myserver
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/server/root
    ProxyPass /myservice/ ajp://localhost:8009/myservice/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key
    ...
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/ca.buddle.pem
</Virtualhost>
```

With this config, I can get the client certificate from

```
http://myserver/myservice/register
```

then access the service using it. Yet, I did not manage to set it to https, so that I can close the 80 port.

Answer (score 2):

Now I got the solution, simply using  or  to exclude the target URL path.

```
<Virtualhost *:443>
    ServerName myserver
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/server/root
    ProxyPass /myservice/register http://localhost:4444/register
    ProxyPass /myservice/ ajp://localhost:8009/myservice/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key
    ...
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/ca.buddle.pem

    <LocationMatch ^/myservice/register$>
        SSLVerifyClient none
    </LocationMatch>

</Virtualhost>
```